# Simplest way to  deserialize an Array/Sequence of objects from XML with C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class `Foo` (assume proper `using` directives)

```
namespace Example
{
    [XmlRoot("foo")]
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo() {}

        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

And an XmlSerializer can deal with XML like this to produce an object of type `Foo`

```
<foo>
    <name>BOSS</name>
</foo>
```

What is the minimal amount of work I can do to make the XmlSerializer handle XML of this form,

```
<foos>
    <foo>
        <name>BOSS</name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <name>NOT A BOSS</name>
    </foo>
</foos>
```

and produce an array of `Foo` objects?

EDIT:

How I'm doing it for a single `Foo`:

```
var xr = new XmlTextReader("foo.xml");
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
var a = (Foo) xs.Deserialize(xr);
```

Potential example for `Foo[]`

```
var xr = new XmlTextReader("foos.xml");
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo[]));
var a = (Foo[]) xs.Deserialize(xr);
```

Comment: Have you written any code that uses the XmlSerializer yet?

Comment: @RQDQ Added some examples of how I'm doing it for a single item, and how I figure it might happen with an array of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge for the simplest. Adding another class Foos and removing the xmlroot tag from class Foo.

```
namespace Example
{
    [XmlRoot("foos")]    
    class Foos
    {
        public Foos() {}

        [XmlElement("foo")]
        public List<Foo> FooList {get; set;}
    }
}
```